# C# Auto generating Class fill Property from enum

Tags: c#, class, enums

Is there away to Auto-generate a full Class Property from an enum or a list?
All of my Property will be bool and  set up like this:

```
  private bool _stop;

    public bool Stop
    {
        get => _stop;
        set
        {
            if (_stop == value) return;
            _stop = value;
            StopChanged?.Invoke(value);
        }
    }  
    public event VariableHasChangedEventHandler StopChanged;
```

I have a long list of these to do, it is so redundant that I feel like there should be a way to Auto generate this code.

I have all the names in an enum and in a static class.

Is there any way of Auto generating that code from a enum or a static class?

I am using visual studio 2022

Answer (score -1):

Yep, that's exactly what [source generators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/roslyn-sdk/source-generators-overview) are for.

Answer (score -1):

Depending on what you want to achieve you could also consider using [code snippets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/walkthrough-creating-a-code-snippet?view=vs-2022). Thus you could mitigate the pain in creating boilerplate code.